# Displaying additional details on click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, dynamic

I am building a site where i will be having a page display product images, product name and a little piece of product description text from my `sql database`.

I want to be able to see the full details of the product when I click on the product name, **how would i go about doing this?**

I am not asking for free code or anything i would just like to be pointed in the right direction.

Also these product pages should be added dynamically when i add a new product to my database products table.

Comment: Does DB has "little piece of product description" as a separate field or is it part of "full detail" ?

Comment: Are you using `MVC`, or just straight `ASP.NET`?

Comment: The Db Has the full description no seperate field

Comment: i am using straight asp.net and c#, i just "create empty website"

Answer (score 3):

Put the product details in a `Panel` and set its visible state to false by default. When the user clicks the image/button/whatever, use client-side code to display the product detail panel.

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    showDetails = function(){
        var el = document.getElementById("productDetails");
        if (el){
            el.style.display = "block";   
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- here is the equivalent of your image -->
<input type="button" value="Show Details" id="btnShowDetails" onclick="showDetails();" />
<!-- here is the equivalent of a panel containing the product details -->
<div id="productDetails" style="display:none;">
    This is a cool product!
</div>
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GRf2K/) is a quick demo so you can see it working. Obviously your implementation will be more complex, but this should get you going in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: I think i am going to go with a panel :)

Answer (score 1):

For a product page to be added dynamically, probably what you're looking for is an `ASHX` handler. You make a single .aspx page that will generically display data for a given product when it receives a parameter. Then the `ASHX` handler works like this: it fetches the relevant part of an URL, parses it for parameters, forwards the request to a given page passing the parameters it extracted, and finally servers the contents of the page. That's a pretty superficial look of one of the functionalities such handlers offer, actually - but do take a look at them.

If you want the product details to show up as an element of a page the user is currently browsing, instead of redirecting them to a new page, you can use `jQuery` to add a `div` (which you can style to look like a baloon or any other gimmick). Inside that `div` you could have an `iframe`, or just a `panel` which you can feed data about the product dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If I would do this I would do it by routing read more here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX

that in turn would look something like this

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Code that runs on application startup
  RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute","Products/{ProductNumber}","~/Webpages/BookStore/ViewBookDemo.aspx");
} 

int productnumber = Convert.ToInt(Page.RouteData.Values["ProductNumber"]);

if (productnumber  != null)
{
    if (ProductNumber == 1)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/css.jpg";
    }
    else if (productnumber == 2)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/django.jpg";
    }
    else if (productnumber == 3)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/iphone.jpg";
    }
    else if (productnumber  == 4)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/Linq.jpg";
    }
  }         
}
```